# how to pass string second parameter in js function of onclick button passed function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am googling from last one days but I never be found what's the problem in my code. 
My append js code is

```
      $('.dynamic-form').append("<div class='row " + field_type + "-field" + field_count + "'>" +
            "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='FieldEdit("+field_count + "," \''+field_type+ '\' +  ")'>" + ' + "</button>");
```

Js funtion is

```
function FieldEdit(id,type) {
    $('#' + type + '-field' + id).toggle();
}
```

I feel so much glad and thankful if any one solve out this issue.
Thanks you!!!!

Comment: console type and id , what are you getting

Comment: You are trying to select an element by its id. You have not shown any HTML element that would have an id, so we have no idea what you are actually trying to select here.

Comment: show this error SyntaxError: illegal character

Comment: What is `field_count` and `field_type`? What do want it to do? What are the results. What are the results you were expecting?

Comment: I just want field_count=1 and field_type should be in string which can be bus,truck,van etc which can be dynamically selected by Id and field_type of the function FieldEdit. but while I am consoling type it's show error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the proper quotes with escape for the second parameter:

```
          ...      "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' 
onClick='FieldEdit(" + field_count + ",\"" + field_type + "\")'></button>");
```

Console output:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' 
   onClick='FieldEdit(1,"This string")'></button>
```

Comment: Thanks @KAD. This can show error while onclick function trigger. Error is like SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'. while I am inspecting html in browser the html should be like this:-  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="FieldEdit(1," bus')=""> Edit </button>

Comment: please try the latest edit, there was a problem with the original answer